# Excel VBA Copy/Paste Without clipboard Define Range

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry if this had been discussed already, I am struggling with the syntax of the ranges that I need to copy and paste. I am trying to do so without using the clipboard and found out that I could do it with `.Value = .Value` ([Excel VBA Copy and Paste (without using Copy+Paste functions) on empty row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32152282/excel-vba-copy-and-paste-without-using-copypaste-functions-on-empty-row))

There are two workbooks, I am copying from `wbsource.Worksheets(1)` to `wb1.ws`

The argument is - if column ***L&row*** has a ***"Yes"*** then ... E.g. if L5 equals Yes, then copy A5:L5 and paste in the first empty row in wb1.ws.

Part of my code is

```
If .Cells(rw, 12) = "Yes" Then
    Dim lastrw As Long
    lastrw = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    wbsource.Worksheets(1).???? = ws.Range("A" & lastrw).Value
End If
```

I would really appreciate it if you could help me with the syntax of this

Comment: It should be `destination.Value = source.Value` where `destination` and `source` are ranges of your choice. So you need to flip your code left/right.

Comment: `ws.Range("A" & lastrw & ":L" & lastrw).Value=wbsource.sheets(1).range("A" & rw & ":L" & rw).value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following should work for you:

```
If wbsource.Worksheets(1).Cells(rw, 12) = "Yes" Then
    Dim lastrw As Long
    lastrw = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ws.Range("A" & lastrw & ":L" & lastrw).Value = wbsource.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & rw & ":L" & rw).Value
End If
```